# Вызов функции из подгружаемого HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Доброго времени суток.
Собственно возникла одна проблема.

Через **AJAX** с интервалом в 5 секунд подгружаю результат выполнения **PHP** скрипта, который выводит информацию в виде таблицы, в последнем столбце таблицы имеется `button`, которым собственно и хочу вывести функцию, которая содержится в подгружаемом на странице **JS** файле. Пробовал вызвать через `class`, реакции никакой не происходило, а через непосредственный вызов функции в консоль писало что функция не существует.

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxDir + "Dispatcher",
    type: "POST",
    method: "post",
    data: {
        "query": "ReturnTransactionConfirmation"
    },
    success: function (request) {
        $("#table-content").html(request);
    }
});
```

Ответ PHP

```
$TableContent .= '<tr style="background: brown; color: white;">';
$TableContent .= '<td style="text-transform: uppercase;border:1px solid black">'.$transaction_date_add.'</td>';
$TableContent .= '<td style="text-transform: uppercase;border:1px solid black"><a href="/dashboard/orders/edit/'.$item['order_id'].'">#'.$item['order_id'].'</a></td>';
$TableContent .= '<td style="text-transform: uppercase;border:1px solid black">Наличный</td>';
$TableContent .= '<td style="text-transform: uppercase;border:1px solid black">Расход</td>';
$TableContent .= '<td style="text-transform: uppercase;border:1px solid black">---------</td>';
$TableContent .= '<td style="text-transform: uppercase;border:1px solid black">'.$item['transaction_amount'].' UAH</td>';
$TableContent .= '<td style="text-transform: uppercase;border:1px solid black">'.$UserNameFrom.'</td>';
$TableContent .= '<td style="text-transform: uppercase;border:1px solid black">---------</td>';
$TableContent .= '<td style="text-transform: uppercase;border:1px solid black;background: white;color:black;"> <button onclick="newButtonNew();" class="success-transaction" data-transaction-id="'.$item['transaction_id'].'" style="margin:10px;">ПОДТВЕРДИТЬ</button> </td>';
$TableContent .= '</tr> ';
```

Функция

```
function newButtonNew() {
    bootbox.confirm({
        message: "Костя, это точно?",
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: 'Да',
                className: 'btn-success'
            },
            cancel: {
                label: 'Нет',
                className: 'btn-danger'
            }
        },
        callback: function (result) {

        }
    });
};
```

Всем спасибо за помощь и внимание )

Comment: А код в вопросе будет приводить Ваш кот?)

Comment: @АлександрБелинский исправился )

Comment: юзаете jquery дак и навешивайте обработчики  соответствующим образом через `$('...').on('click', ....)`

Comment: @teran спасибо, помогло )

Comment: Корень проблемы тут, видимо, в том, что определенная функция находится вне области видимости. Думаю если например её вынести в глобальную область видимости window.newButtonNew = function () { ... } то заработает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно спасибо [teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran) за помощь в решение данного вопроса )

```
 $('body').on('click', '.success-transaction', function () {

         //Что-то делаем

    });
```

Comment: оптимально будет брать не `body`, а ближайшего предка, который находится в дереве DOM.